# NetSuite API - Adding "Item Group" under a Sales Order

Tags: api, integration, netsuite, itemgroup

I am trying to integrate with NetSuite API to create Sales Orders. It works fine when I add Non-inventory items. However, when I add Item groups through the API, it fails with the error "Please enter a value for amount".

What I tried so far:
-> Added the Item Group Header Item 
-> Added all the line items under the Item group
-> Added the "end of group" line item (item id = '0')
->I have set quantity and rate for all the lines

Yet it fails with the above error. What is the right way to add an item group to a Sales Order Line in NetSuite?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: would you be willing to share the body of your post?  I'm stuck on Sales Order Items, and it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but see if you are using the "custom" price level.
Use custom price levels and set the amount too.

Comment: Your input worked. I added some default base price for the item and I was able to successfully add the bundle. Thanks!

Comment: A followup question - Is there a way to locally manipulate the components of the bundle (add new items to the bundle) before it is inserted?

Comment: I need more information. 

1> Are you creating the bundle to migrate from testing to prod.? or is this an external bundle?

2>What do you exactly mean by before inserted?

Usually, if the bundle is externally managed, and locked, I don't think we can manipulate the components. But if it is not locked you can make updates to the components.